# Передвижение персонажа

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть объект,он может поворачиваться, также я хотел сделать ему ход вперёд. Я знаю что есть transform.forward Vector3, а у меня 2D объект.

Comment: в Vector3 используйте просто нужные вам координаты XY, YZ, XZ, не использую третью, тогда у Вас получиться, что уже пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, двигается также, относительно координат мира. В итоге решил проблему с помощью AddForce